# java md5 hash, php function to check

Tags: java, php, hash, md5

so here is a java function that already exists

```
StringBuffer sbTemp = new StringBuffer();
byte[] btTypeInPasswd = this.md.digest(this.password.getBytes());

for (int i = 0; i < btTypeInPasswd.length; i++)
  sbTemp = sbTemp.append(btTypeInPasswd[i]);

this.password = sbTemp.toString();
```

this.password would then contain a string like follows if the password was test:    -8774-113-27-52-79-101-9028768115-45-111-23-121-10447-69-45

What I need is a PHP function to produce the same result, can this be done?

I **can NOT** edit the java .class file as this is part of an existing application I wish to work along-side by accessing it's existing database.

This is what I tried.

```
$bytes = md5("test", true);
$bArray = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < strlen($bytes); $x++)
    $bArray[$x] = ord(substr($bytes, $x, 1));

print "<pre>" . implode('-', $numbers) . "</pre>";
```

However using the same password "test" it produces: 9-143-107-205-70-33-211-115-202-222-78-131-38-39-180-246 not at all like -8774-113-27-52-79-101-9028768115-45-111-23-121-10447-69-45

Thanks.

Comment: Holy crap, I made a mistake by not posting what I've tried, I just assumed everyone would figure I've tried the obvious stuff like ord, pack/unpack etc... my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So no thanks to trolls, if anyone else needs to know how to do this here is how.

```
function md5_hash($password)
{
    $hashArray = array();
    $hash = md5($password);

    for ($x = 0; $x < strlen($hash); $x += 2)
        $hashArray[$x] = (($dec = hexdec(substr($hash, $x, 2))) > 127 ? $dec - 256 : $dec);

    return implode("", $hashArray);
}
```

Using the password "test" will result in the above function returning a string: 9-113107-517033-45115-54-3478-1253839-76-10

Comment: Trolls run free on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a built-in `md5()` function that given a string returns a 32 character *hexadecimal* digest, e.g:

```
<? echo md5('test'); ?>
```

gives:

```
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

So if you fix your Java code to output hex instead of decimal, the results *should* match.

Comment: This is not an option as I have no control over the java code, it's already set in stone as it's part of an existing application I simply want to work in PHP along side it, accessing it's existing databases.

Answer (score 0):

```
$md5 = md5('...... your string here ....');
$numbers = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($md5); $i++) {
   $numbers[i] = ord(substr($md5, $i, 1));
}

echo implode('-', $numbers);
```

Comment: This does not work I had to edit you're function a bit like this `$md5 = md5("test", true);
  $numbers = array();
  
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($md5); $i++)
   $numbers[$i] = ord(substr($md5, $i, 1));
   
  print "<pre>" . implode('-', $numbers) . "</pre>";` however that will produce: 9-143-107-205-70-33-211-115-202-222-78-131-38-39-180-246

Answer (score 0):

above `md5_hash` function in one line, You can do:

```
$password  = implode("", unpack('c*', md5($password,true)));
```